# IndexError out of range but it Is in range

Tags: python, list, dictionary

ratings_dict is a dictionary with the format: {'userName' : [0, 0, 1, 0, etc]}
I'm attempting to access each element in the list (in the dictionary) and it is giving me a specific error at 'if ratings_dict[name][i] is not 0:' and it is saying that IndexError: list index out of range.

Edited: This is my revised code. As you can see from the traceback, the value at ratings_dict['Martin'][0] is 1. 
I have also revised my code in mind of your efficiency tips.. 
I am still at a loss at what to do.

```
def calculate_average_rating(ratings_dict):
    ratings = {}
    numBooks = len(ratings_dict)
    print ratings_dict['Martin'][0]
    for i in range(numBooks):
        x = 0
        sum = 0
        numR = 0
        for name in ratings_dict:
            if ratings_dict[name][x] != 0:
                sum = sum + ratings_dict[name][x]
                numR += 1
                x = x + 1
        if numR is 0:
            ratings[i] = 0

        if sum != 0:
            ratings[i] = float(sum) / float(numR)

    return ratings
```

Output:

```
1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Collin\Dropbox\Python Files\main.py", line 106, in     <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\Collin\Dropbox\Python Files\main.py", line 103, in main
    print calculate_average_rating(ratingsDict)
  File "C:\Users\Collin\Dropbox\Python Files\main.py", line 10, in     calculate_average_rating
    if ratings_dict[name][x] != 0:
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: Can you post an testable example of `ratings_dict`?

Comment: As an aside, you should not use `is not 0`, you should use `!= 0`

Comment: You could always print the element which is giving the IndexError, then you will see why it's failing.

Comment: Anyway, your claim that since `print ratings_dict['Martin'][0]` prints something, that you can't have an index-error, is wrong. It's impossible to say what is causing you error without seeing the data exactly that produces it. Likely, the issue is that you are itarting over `range(numBooks)`, but the lists in the `dict` do not have the same length. This would be solved by not iterating over a range, but iterating over the lists directly.

Comment: Also, no need for `Names = ratings_dict.keys()` and then `for name in Names`. Just `for name in ratings_dict:`. Iterating over a dictionary iterates over the keys. If you use `ratings_dict.keys()` it is less efficient because it *creates a list of keys every time*.

Comment: Please fix the indentation of the code in your post, it is unclear which lines are supposed to be inside `def calculate_average_rating`.

Comment: {'Priscilla': [5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 3, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -3, 1, 0, 1, 0, -3]}
the key is the username. In this case Priscilla, the value would be this list of integers.

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: also, numBooks is the length of the dictionary, not the length of a single list in the dictionary. . Unless I do have it backwards.

Answer (score 3):

If you're getting an index error but don't "believe" that you should be, just print out the list and you will see the problem.

```
a = [0]
```

Imagine you didn't know what `a` was and then ran this code:

```
for i in range(2):
    try :
        x = a[i]
    except IndexError:
        print('IndexError, list = ' + str(a) + ', index = ' + str(i))
```

Then you would see

```
IndexError, list = [0], index = 1
```

and so the problem is clear.  If the list is too long to print nicely, you can simply print the length instead of the list.

Comment: I have edited my code and shown the output. There is a value in the list.

Comment: No, you have proven nothing with your code about what happens inside the loop, because you only printed the first value (before looping).  Add this try-except block and you will see your problem.

Answer (score 0):

As others have already pointed out, it is very hard to say what is causing the `IndexError` without looking at `ratings_dict`. Most likely, the error is happening because the list containing the ratings has different length for different users. You are calculating the length using `len(ratings_dict[Names[0]])`, which is the length of the list corresponding to the first (i.e. 0th user). If the second user's list has a shorter length, then you will get an `IndexError`.

In more detail, here's what I mean. Suppose your ratings_dict is as follows:

```
ratings_dict = {"martin" : [1, 4, 3, 4, 5],
                "tom" : [0, 1, 2, 1, 5], 
                "christina" : [0, 0, 2, 2, 3],
                }
```

and we use the following function (I basically simplified your function a little bit)

```
def calculate_average_rating(ratings_dict):
    names = [key for key in ratings_dict]
    numBooks = len(ratings_dict[names[0]])
    ratings = []
    for i in range(numBooks):
        total = 0
        for name in names:
            if ratings_dict[name][i] != 0:
                total = total + ratings_dict[name][i]

        ratings.append(float(total) / len(names))

    return ratings
```

then we get no `IndexError`.

```
calculate_average_rating(ratings_dict)
[0.3333333333333333,
 1.6666666666666667,
 2.3333333333333335,
 2.3333333333333335,
 4.333333333333333]
```

However, if we Christina has reviewed an additional book and `ratings_dict` looks as follows:

```
ratings_dict = {"martin" : [1, 4, 3, 4, 5],
                "tom" : [0, 1, 2, 1, 5], 
                "christina" : [0, 0, 2, 2, 3, 6],
                }
```

then running the function gives an IndexError:

```
calculate_average_rating(ratings_dict)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-23-1ad9c374e8d8> in <module>()
----> 1 calculate_average_rating(ratings_dict)

<ipython-input-14-080a1623f225> in calculate_average_rating(ratings_dict)
      6         total = 0
      7         for name in names:
----> 8             if ratings_dict[name][i] != 0:
      9                 total = total + ratings_dict[name][i]
     10 

IndexError: list index out of range
```

It happens because the lists of different users do not have equal length.

Slightly off topic, it is not considered good practice to use capital letters to start variable names, because it can be confused for being a `Class`. See [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#prescriptive-naming-conventions) for more details. Therefore, consider changing `Names` to `names`.

Secondly, you shouldn't use `is not` for doing comparisons. In this particular case, it won't bite you. But in some cases, it will. For example:

```
>>> a = 1000
>>> b = 1000
>>> a is b
False
```

The `is` operator compares whether `a` and `b` are the same objects, and not their values. In this case, `a` and `b` are *different* objects with the same value, therefore `a is b` evaluates to `False`.

Comment: Fixed that. Does my new code make sense? I'm still trying to figure out why I am getting an index error..

Comment: I edited the answer to explain what I mean in more detail. Does that help?